# How do I preserve Telerik MVC grid column order and sizes when paging?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I have a Telerik ASP.NET MVC grid that uses server data binding and has column resizing and reordering enabled.  If I manually re-order or re-size the columns and then use the grid pager to jump to another page of the grid, the column sizes and order revert back to the default settings.  What is the best way to preserve user changes to the column size and order when paging?

On the Telerik demos site I found an example that uses hidden form fields with AJAX data binding, but as far as I know that won't work for the server binding HTTP GETs. I started down the path of using cookies instead of hidden form fields, but it started getting messy and I was looking for feedback on alternative approaches.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the column widths down to the grid either as part of your model or with ViewBag (or ViewData if you're using MVC 2)

You can then set your column widths using:

```
.Width((int)ViewBag.col1Width);
```

- or -

```
.Width((int)model.col1Width);
```

You can then update the values using a callback via the `OnColumnResize` event (this is raised when a grid column is resized by the user)

If you're using session state, you could also store the values in session variables if they are to persist throughout the user's session.